# Get external javascript file to work in joomla

Tags: joomla-2.5, javascript, jfactory, external-script, wrapper

I have a menu using IFrame Wrapper so that I can link to my own coded php page. 
Inside the php file is just listing down the data on table and I have search box so that user can filter the data onkeyup.
The javascript works if I put the javascript inside the html.

```
<html>
<script>
function doSearch() {
var searchtext = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;
var targetTable = document.getElementById('table');
var targetTableColCount;

//Loop through table rows
for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < targetTable.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
    var rowData = '';

    //Get column count from header row
    if (rowIndex == 0) {
       targetTableColCount = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.length;
       continue; //do not execute further code for header row.
    }

    //Process data rows. (rowIndex >= 1)
    for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < targetTableColCount; colIndex++) {
        rowData += targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex).textContent;
    }

    //If search term is not found in row data
    //then hide the row, else show
    if (rowData.indexOf(searchtext) == -1)
        targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'none';
    else
        targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row';
   }
}
</script>
<body>
<form name="searchbox" id="searchbox" method="POST" action="#">
 <input type="text" id="searchTerm" placeholder=" search.." onkeyup="doSearch()" />
</form>
<?php
 if(empty($folderlist))
  {
   echo "<br>";
   echo "<p style='color:red;'>You don't have any acccessible folders.</p>";
  }
 else {
 ?>
<table id="table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>No. </th>
    <th>Folders </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php for($a = 0; $a < count($folderlist); $a++){ ?>
<tr>
    <td>
    <?php echo $a+1; ?>.
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&<?php echo $folderlist[$a]->getPath(); ?>" target="_top" ><?php echo $folderlist[$a]->getDesc(); ?><a>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
  <?php }
 echo "</table>";
 }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But I want to use external filter.js with the same javascript code instead of using internal js file like html file above. I declare below code on top of the html file but it does not work.

```
  define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
  define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root
  define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
  require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
  require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

  $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
  $mainframe->initialise();
  $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
  $doc->addScript(JURI::root().'filter.js');
```

I put the filter.js on the root folder in joomla.

Comment: `$doc->addScript()` includes a Javascript file in `head` tags. You can't do this outside of Joomla. If you need to include a JS file, simply use `<script src="path/to/file">` like you would in HTML

Comment: silly me, haha, it works as you suggested, thanks!!! I have another question tho, I realised the js code filter with sensitive case, if I put toLowerCase() in this line (rowData.indexOf(searchtext) == -1), it filters the list without case sensitive, but once I put capital letters, the results are zero, is there a way that I can filter both insensitive n sensitive case?

Comment: I'd suggest asking a new question on Stackoverflow for that ;)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are trying to add code without following Joomla! practices. Then, it is going to be difficult to achieve what your are looking for.

- For instance, Javascript code is generally located in /media folder.
- Also, a PHP file without "defined('_JEXEC') or die();" is a bad idea, not following the general security rule to prevent direct access to internal PHP files.
- Finally, htaccess has several rules to block direct access to certain files.

To add raw code, it is better to install an extension following a controlled way. Please, check this JED category: [Coding & Scripts Integration](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration)